# How can I prevent alphabetical sorting of query parameter in Spring Boot RestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, query-string, resttemplate

Because of our company infrastructure and security guidelines I had to write a proxy to enable other services to communicate with an external API. The flow of a sample request would be a GET from a service to

`https://internal-proxy.com/matrix?member=one&version=1&member=two&version=42&member=seven&version=1`

which should forward the request to

`https://external-api.com/matrix?member=one&version=1&member=two&version=42&member=seven&version=1`

The proxy service is written with Spring Boot 3 and uses the RestTemplate to execute the outgoing call:

```java
var targetUrl = requestUrl.replace(internalUrl, externalUrl);
var queryString = request.getQueryString();
if (null != queryString && !queryString.isEmpty()) {
    targetUrl = targetUrl
            .concat("?")
            .concat(queryString);
}

HttpHeaders headers = getRequestHeaders(request);

HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

DefaultUriBuilderFactory defaultUriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
defaultUriBuilderFactory.setParsePath(false);
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);

try {
    ResponseEntity<String> serverResponse = restTemplate.exchange(targetUrl, method, httpEntity, String.class);
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that in the call of `restTemplate.exchange` the `targetUrl` is interpreted, the query parameters extracted and ordered alphabetically. So that the outgoing call is

`https://external-api.com/matrix?member=one&member=two&member=seven&version=1&version=42&version=1`

Now the external API cannot match the versions to the members. Yes, the design of the external API is broken. But is there any chance that I can keep the query parameters in the order they appear in the `targetUrl`?

I already tried adding the query parameters manually using a URI in `restTemplate.execute()`:

```java
uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri)
                .path(requestUrl)
                .queryParam("member", "one")
                .queryParam("version", "2")
                .queryParam("member", "three")
                .queryParam("version", "2")
                .queryParam("member", "seven")
                .queryParam("version", "2")
                .build(false).toUri();
```

Which also didn't work and the `queryParam` got ordered again.